# How to get the last value from multiple checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

This my checkbox elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue" /> Blue <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="green" /> Green<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="yellow" /> Yellow<br/>
```

How can i get the last value from this multiple checkbox, just clear JS because i have been studying JS and HTML just  for 2 days. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll`

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=colors]")
var lastCheckbox = checkboxes[checkboxes.length - 1];
var lastCheckboxValue = lastCheckbox.value;
```